# How to configure Apache to handle two reverse proxies one one domain/server name?

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js

I've got a node-react app on port 3000, and a node/express API running on port 3001 (localhost:3001/api). I need a reverse proxy setup in Apache that will put the React app on `https://example.domain.com/` and the API on `https://example.domain.com/api`.

Will this work?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.domain.com
    [SSL Configuration]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/api" "http://localhost:3001/api"

</VirtualHost>
```

If that won't work, what will work? another `<VirtualHost>` listing?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMaaS

The documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass offers two  options:

---

**Alternative 1:**

> ## Ordering ProxyPass Directives
>
> The configured `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` rules are checked in the order of configuration. ***The first rule that matches wins***. So usually you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest URLs first. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL. Note that there is some relation with worker sharing.

In other words order matters and your ProxyPass directives should be ordered as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.domain.com

    ProxyPass "/api" "http://localhost:3001/api"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://localhost:3001/api"

    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000"
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Alternative 2:**

> ## Ordering ProxyPass Directives in `<Location>`s
>
> Only one ProxyPass directive can be placed in a Location block, and the most specific location will take precedence.

In other words when using `Location` block syntax the ordering doesn't matter and the effect should be the same when you switch the two location blocks around:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.domain.com

    <Location "/">
       ProxyPass  "http://localhost:3000"
       ProxyPassReverse  "http://localhost:3000"
    </Location>

    <Location "/api">
       ProxyPass  "http://localhost:3001/api"
       ProxyPassReverse  "http://localhost:3001/api"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost
```

Comment: Thank you so much!